# compare values in a hash and return the matching key

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, key-value-observing

I'm trying to look through a hash and compare it's values to an existing string and then when the match is found I want to output its key.  I trying to write this in a code block and output the result to the console.

```
officer.name = "Dave"

@hash = { "Tom" => "97", "Dave" => "98", "John" => "99" }

@hash.each { |key, value| do
    if #{key} == officer.name
        puts "id: #{value}"
    else
        puts "no match"
    end
}
```

Right now my console outputs:

```
 id: 97
 no match
 id: 98
 no match
 id: 99
 no match
```

I'm trying to get it to output just the value of #{value} based on it's matching #{key}, which in this case would be Dave.  So for the above example I want my console to spit just the number 98 or "no match".

Comment: Why wouldn't you just access the value using the key? Why iterate? Also, your title is the reverse of your code and text.

Comment: `if #{key} == officer.name` : everything after the `#` is a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a hash! You can do what you attempt way more efficiently:

```
officer.name = "Dave"

@hash = { "Tom" => "97", "Dave" => "98", "John" => "99" }

unless @hash.key?(officer.name) 
  puts "no match"
else 
  puts "id: #{@hash[officer.name]}"
end
```

Comment: Why putting an `unless else end` statement... ?

Answer (score 3):

Is it because you forgot the " ?

```
if "#{key}" == officer.name
```

but you could just do

```
if key == officer.name
```

Comment: Or you don't need to interpolate at all?

Answer (score 2):

```
officer.name = "Dave"

@hash = { "Tom" => "97", "Dave" => "98", "John" => "99" }

@hash.each do |key, value|
  if key == officer.name
    puts key
  else
    puts "no match"
  end
end
```

This should work

Answer (score 2):

```
@hash.has_key?(officer.name) ? @hash[officer.name] : "no match"
```

Answer (score 1):

When doing hash lookups by key, avoid #[].  Favor #fetch instead:

```
officer.name = "Dave"
@hash = { "Tom" => "97", "Dave" => "98", "John" => "99" }
puts @hash.fetch(officer.name, 'no match')
```

#fetch allows you to specify a default value other than nil, which will prevent unexpected nils from hash lookups from throwing the all-too-common NoMethodError.

Answer (score 1):

this works too. slight edit from original post.
it prints out answer for each pair though and doesn't identify which pair the answer refers to.

```
officer = "Dave"

@hash = { "Tom" => "97", "Dave" => "98", "John" => "99" }

@hash.each do |key, value|
    if key == officer
    puts key
  else
    puts "no match"
  end
end
```